# Did Jim Butcher screw up?

Tags: the-dresden-files

In the latest Dresden File novel Dresden and Valmont say that Nicodemus hired Valmont and the church mice to steal the shroud of Turin, but in the book where it occured it was Marcone that hired them as far as I can remember

Was this just a screw up on the writers part or am I misremembering?

Comment: You're not the only person to point out [this as well as other inconsistencies](http://www.reddit.com/r/dresdenfiles/comments/26q2v2/skin_game_spoilers_inconsistencies_that_arent/).